# Resizing d3 generated SVG on window resize shifts my chart data incorrectly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have 5 div elements to contain 5 svgs. Their id's are numerical and programmatically  generated:

```
<div id="svg-container-total"></div>
<div id="svg-container-3"></div>
<div id="svg-container-6"></div>
<div id="svg-container-12"></div>
<div id="svg-container-24"></div>
```

I create some variables and use techan.js to define scale, ranges, etc. Note that it's ok to use #svg-container-total to define the width because all the svg's will be created equally

```
//defining misc variables
var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 80, left: 60},
    width = parseInt(d3.select('#svg-container-total').style('width'),10) - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Defining chart scale
var x = techan.scale.financetime()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

//initializing chart data function
var close = techan.plot.close()
    .xScale(x)
    .yScale(y);
```

I then enter a loop to create all the SVG's. My data is just some price data:

```
// INSERT SVG (IN THE LOOP NOW)
var svg = d3.select("#svg-container-"+frequency).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var accessor = close.accessor();

x.domain(data.map(accessor.d));
y.domain(techan.scale.plot.ohlc(data,accessor).domain());

svg.append("g")
   .datum(data)
   .attr("class", "performance_"+frequency)
   .call(close);
```

So far so good. Here are the results. There are now 5 graphs like the one below in 5 separate rows.
[image]

I now defined a resize function and listen for window resize (Note that the frequencies array allows me to loop through the different svg containers):

```
function resize() {
    //Find new window dimensions
    width = parseInt(d3.select('#svg-container-total').style('width'), 10);
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right;

    //Update range of scale with new width
    x.range([0, width]);

    for (var i = 0; i<frequencies.length; i++) {
        //Update chart contents
        d3.select("#svg-container-"+frequencies[i]+" svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        d3.selectAll(".performance_"+frequencies[i])
          .call(close);
    }
}
```

However my result now looks something like this:
[image]

Everything seems to be resizing correctly except for the actual data points. It seems like the data points are always shifted vertically by some amount. Each graph seems to be shifted vertically by different amounts, although their shifts are consistent every time I hit refresh and resize the window again.

I think the issue is related to the several SVG's accessing this same variable:

```
var close = techan.plot.close()
```

but I don't know why it would shift the data vertically. Additionally since all the graphs are of the same height and width, I don't think accessing "close" multiple times in a loop would be an issue.

I thought this way because this issue DOES NOT OCCUR when I render only one graph.

Any ideas?

Reference: http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/af8674d57980790137a0

Answer (score 0):

1.after:

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg-container-"+frequency).append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

insert:

```
var defs = svg.append("defs"); 
    defs.append("clipPath").attr('id','clip-path'+frequency)
    .append('rect').attr('width',width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height',height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

2.find in your code and insert:

```
.attr('clip-path','url(#clip-path'+frequency')')
```

Example (in my code):

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width) 
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+width+" "+ height)
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMax none")
    .attr("xml:space","preserve")
    .attr("shape-rendering","optimizeSpeed") 
    .attr("id", "chart1")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding.left + "," + padding.top + ")")
    .attr("id", "layers")
    .on("click", dvevent) 
    .call(d3.zoom()
        .duration(-1)
        .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .scaleExtent([1, 20])
        .on("zoom", zoomed));

  var defs = svg.append("defs"); defs.append("clipPath").attr('id','clip-path').append('rect').attr('width',width).attr('height',height);

 var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .attr('clip-path','url(#clip-path)')

...skipped...

 var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {return d.filter(function(d,i) { ...skipped... })})
    .enter().append("rect")

...skipped...
```

Comment: Hi, I appended .attr('clip-path','url(#clip-path'+frequencies[i]+')'); in my resize function on my d3.select("#svg-container-"+frequencies[i]+" svg"), but it didn't work. Do you mind explaining what this is doing?

Comment: Hi, I don't know. I need example on jsfiddle.net or other.